# KnockoutJS : ko.ToJSON(this) does not work?

Tags: knockout.js, knockout-mapping-plugin

The following java-script which defines the MyViewModel object with a property "**text**" and a function "**save**".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function MyViewModel() {
        this.text = ko.observable('');
    }

    MyViewModel.prototype.save = function () {
        alert(this.text()); // Works fine
        var data = ko.ToJSON(this); // Error: Object doesn't support this property or method ?
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/Person/Save',
            data: data,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            }
        });
    };
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function () {
        var viewModel = new MyViewModel()
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
    });
</script>
```

And the following button defined:

```
<button data-bind="click: save">SAVE</button>
```

**Result when the button is clicked:**

- Accessing a property using this.text() works fine
- Converting the java-script object to a JSON object : ko.ToJSON(this) does not work
  and throws an error: "Error: Object doesn't support this property or
  method"

Probably something trivial is missing or wrong, but I can't see it. Any tips ?

Comment: That's a nice pattern to be using - and it will work if you use `toJSON` rather than `ToJSON` (Knockout fully supports this pattern, you just had a typo in your code).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Knockout doesn't have a `ToJSON` method - it does have a [`toJSON`](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/json-data.html) method though:

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.text = ko.observable('');
}

MyViewModel.prototype.save = function () {
    alert(this.text()); // Works fine
    var data = ko.toJSON(this); // Works fine too
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/Person/Save',
        data: data,
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {
            alert(data);
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Sean thanks for your help. (Sometimes it is very simple). For some reason javascript Intellisense was not working correctly, so I didn't see this error.

Comment: Add the following references in the starting of your javascript file
///<reference path="~/put your path knockout.js file path here">

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your view model as a function (a class, if you like):

```
function MyViewModel() {
    this.text = ko.observable('');
}
```

Instead, you should define it as a var (an object):

```
var MyViewModel = {
    text: ko.observable('');
}
```

You should then find that the following works fine:

```
var data = ko.ToJSON(MyViewModel);
```

Comment: I see, but I don't understand why I'm able to access a property from an object, but not the object itself?

Comment: I think it is to do with the difference between the first being a function declaration and the second being a function expression. This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754538/javascript-object-literal-notation-vs-plain-functions-and-performance-implicatio

Comment: @MarkRobinson - actually, Knockout supports using `this` in the way Stef is using it - Knockout simply does not have a `ToJSON` method (the method he's looking for is `toJSON`.

Comment: It makes no difference declaring as inline object or as a method. It only matters if you need to use this, say for a ko.dependable as in-line objects don't support this as keyword.