# How to create a JavaScript "class" that adds methods to prototype AND uses 'this' correctly

Tags: javascript, methods, prototype, this

I've always been taught the correct way to simulate a class in JavaScript is by adding methods to the prototype outside the function that will be your class, like this:

```
function myClass()
{
    this.myProp = "foo";
}

myClass.prototype.myMethod = function()
{
    console.log(this);
}

myObj = new myClass();
myObj.myMethod();
```

I've been running into the issue that the `this` in my methods resolves to the global Window object, [as explained best on quirksmode](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html).

I've tried doing the `var that = this;` trick Koch mentions, but since my methods are outside my class, my `that` variable is no longer in scope.  Perhaps I'm just not understanding it completely.

Is there a way I can create a class in JavaScript where methods are not recreated each implementation and `this` will always point to the object?

**EDIT:**

The simplified code above works but I've had many times where I declare a "class" exactly like above and when I call `myObj.myMethod()`, it comes back as a `Window` object.  I've read over every explanation of `this` that I could find, such as the one I linked to and still don't understand why this problem sometimes happens.  Any idea of a situation where the code could be written like above and `this` would refer to `Window`?

Here's the implementation I'm currently having problems with, but when I simplify it down like above into a few lines, I no longer have the problem:

HTML File:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/class.Database.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/class.ServerFunctionWrapper.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/class.DataUnifier.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./scripts/main.js"></script>
```

class.DataUnifier.js:

```
function DataUnifier()
{
    this._local = new Database();
    this._server = new ServerFunctionWrapper();
    this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = null;
}

DataUnifier.prototype.getUpdates = function()
{
    this._server.getUpdates(updateCommands)
    {
        console.log(updateCommands);
        if (updateCommands)
        {
            executeUpdates(updateCommands);
        }
    }
}
//interval is in seconds
DataUnifier.prototype.startAutoUpdating = function(interval)
{
    this.stopAutoUpdating();
    this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = setInterval(this.getUpdates,interval * 1000);
}
DataUnifier.prototype.stopAutoUpdating = function()
{
    if (this.autoUpdateIntervalObj !== null)
    {
        clearInterval(this.autoUpdateIntervalObj);
        this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = null;
    }
}
```

main.js

```
var dataObj = new DataUnifier();

$(document).ready(function ev_document_ready() {
    dataObj.startAutoUpdating(5);
}
```

I've cut out some code that shouldn't matter but maybe it does.  When the page loads and dataObj.startAutoUpdating(5) is called, it breaks at the this.stopAutoUpdating(); line because `this` refers to the `Window` object.  As far as I can see (and according to the link provided), `this` should refer to the DataUnifier object.  I have read many sources on the `this` keyword and don't understand why I keep running into this problem.  I do not use inline event registration.  Is there any reason code formatted like this would have this problem?

**EDIT 2:** For those with similar issues, see "The `this` problem" half way down the page in this Mozilla docs page: http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your posted code.  Run it, it'll work fine.

Comment: @PointedEars I am well aware there are no classes in JavaScript.  Thanks. I meant "simulating classes." I'll post more code shortly and we'll see if we can tell what's going on.

Comment: @PointedEars Calling this a duplicate of that question is quite a stretch. Rather, a better understanding of `this` would have helped me, which the other question provides. A link to the other question might have been better. I tried to show I had done research by providing a very similar link in my question to yours, but still didn't quite grasp why my implementation wasn't working (which I found out wasn't the problem). My question was is there a way to simulate a class where I wouldn't run into issues with `this`. I couldn't find a question on SO like that.

Comment: @PointedEars I had thoroughly read up on it and thought I understood but was just short of getting it. I was also plenty clear in my original question I understood there was no such thing as JavaScript classes. I purposely used wording like "simulate a class" because I *knew* someone would post that. Just being honest, not confrontational - I was left feeling like you did a drive by glance, didn't fully read, and panned me: http://goo.gl/gpRgVt. I'm certain I can improve, but I tried very hard with this question to follow the guidelines and provide a good question for SO.

Comment: @PointedEars Anyway, I do thank you for trying to help me. Frequent contributors keep SO alive and pumping, so thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My favorite way of defining classes is as follows:

```
function defclass(prototype) {
    var constructor = prototype.constructor;
    constructor.prototype = prototype;
    return constructor;
}
```

Using the `defclass` function you can define `MyClass` as follows:

```
var MyClass = defclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this.myProp = "foo";
    },
    myMethod: function () {
        console.log(this.myProp);
    }
});
```

BTW your actual problem is not with classes. It's the way you're calling `this.getUpdates` from `setTimeout`:

```
this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = setInterval(this.getUpdates, interval * 1000);
```

Instead it should be:

```
this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = setInterval(function (self) {
    return self.getUpdates();
}, 1000 * interval, this);
```

Hence your `DataUnifier` class can be written as:

```
var DataUnifier = defclass({
    constructor: function () {
        this._local = new Database;
        this._server = new ServerFunctionWrapper;
        this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = null;
    },
    getUpdates: function () {
        this._server.getUpdates(function (updateCommands) {
            console.log(updateCommands);
            if (updateCommands) executeUpdates(updateCommands);
        });
    },
    startAutoUpdating: function (interval) {
        this.stopAutoUpdating();
        this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = setInterval(function (self) {
            return self.getUpdates();
        }, 1000 * interval, this);
    },
    stopAutoUpdating: function () {
        if (this.autoUpdateIntervalObj !== null) {
            clearInterval(this.autoUpdateIntervalObj);
            this.autoUpdateIntervalObj = null;
        }
    }
});
```

Succinct isn't it? If you need inheritance then take a look at [`augment`](https://github.com/javascript/augment).

**Edit:** As pointed out in the comments passing additional parameters to `setTimeout` or `setInterval` doesn't work in Internet Explorer versions lesser than 9. The following shim can be used to fix this problem:

```
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script>
        (function (f) {
            window.setTimeout = f(window.setTimeout);
            window.setInterval = f(window.setInterval);
        })(function (f) {
            return function (c, t) {
                var a = [].slice.call(arguments, 2);

                return f(function () {
                    c.apply(this, a);
                }, t);
            };
        });
    </script>
<![endif]-->
```

Since the code is only executed conditionally on Internet Explorer versions lesser than 9 it is completely unobtrusive. Just include it before all your other scripts and your code will work on every browser.

Comment: Good answer, but note that passing `this` as an additional argument to `setInterval` like that doesn't work in Internet Explorer.

Comment: You can always use a shim for `setInterval` and `setTimeout` in Internet Explorer.

Comment: Yes, +2 if I could upvote again :)

Comment: Thanks Aadit. I fixed it with `var self = this;
setInterval(function(){ self.getUpdates(); }, interval * 1000);`. I understood the owner concept with `this`, just not how it works with passing.  For others with this same problem, I found a really good overview of `this` used in setInterval here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setInterval. Go half way down the page to "The "`this`" problem".

Answer (score 2):

**The Answer**

The problem is not with `this.stopAutoUpdating();`, it is with:

```
setInterval(this.getUpdates, interval * 1000);
```

When you pass a function like this to `setInterval` it will be called from the event loop, with no knowledge of the `this` you have here. Note that `this` has nothing to do with how a function is defined, and everything to do with how it is called. You can get around it by passing in an anonymous function:

```
var self = this;
setInterval(function(){ self.getUpdates(); }, interval * 1000);
```

In any modern engine you can use the much nicer [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

```
setInterval(this.getUpdates.bind(this), interval * 1000);
```

You can also use `bind` in older engines if you [shim](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind#Compatibility) it first.

---

**Understanding the Problem**

I recommend that you read about [call](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [apply](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply) for a better understanding.

Note that when you call a function normally, without using bind, call, or apply, then the `this` will just be set to whichever object context the function was called from (that is, whatever comes before the `.`).

Hopefully this helps you understand what I said about `this` not being about how the function is defined, rather how it is called. Here is an example, where you might not expect `this` to work, but it does:

```
// This function is not defined as part of any object
function some_func() {
  return this.foo;
}
some_func(); // undefined (window.foo or an error in strict mode)

var obj = {foo: 'bar'};

// But when called from `obj`'s context `this` will refer to obj:

some_func.call(obj); // 'bar'

obj.getX = some_func;
obj.getX(); // 'bar'
```

An example where you might expect it to work, but it doesn't, along with a couple solutions to make it work again:

```
function FooBar() {
  this.foo = 'bar';
}
FooBar.prototype.getFoo = function() {
  return this.foo;
}

var fb = new FooBar;
fb.getFoo(); // 'bar'

var getFoo = fb.getFoo;

// getFoo is the correct function, but we're calling it without context
// this is what happened when you passed this.getUpdates to setInterval
getFoo(); // undefined (window.foo or an error in strict mode)

getFoo.call(fb); // bar'

getFoo = getFoo.bind(fb);
getFoo(); // 'bar'
```

Comment: Thank you! Sometimes I wish I could mark two answers as accepted. I understood the whole owner thing, I was confused over what context setInterval would call my function from.

Comment: shouldn't `fb.getFoo(); // 'foo'` in your last example be `fb.getFoo(); // 'bar'` since it outputs 'bar'..

Answer (score 0):

There is no "correct" way to simulate classes. There are different patterns you could use.
You could stick with the one you are using right now. The code you posted works correctly. Or you could switch to another pattern.

For example Douglas Crockford advocates doing something like this

```
function myClass() {
    var that = {},
        myMethod = function() {
            console.log(that);
        };
    that.myMethod = myMethod;
    return that;
}
```

Watch his talk on youtube.
http://youtu.be/6eOhyEKUJko?t=48m25s

Comment: Douglas Crockford has had a few good ideas; this is one of the worse ones. Instead of `that`, you could have simply written `this`: `var that = {myMethod: function () { console.log(this); }};`. All the `that` reference does is to *increase* the length of the effective scope chain, implicitly adding a *closure*, thus [*decreasing* the efficiency of the code](https://developers.google.com/speed/articles/optimizing-javascript), and to *hinder* the reuse of the method because it is tied to its owner. Just don’t.

Comment: There are widely varying opinions about this. Sure it can reduce performance a little but that will not be noticeable in most cases. The purpose of this design is to get rid of the broken behaviour of "this" which is responsible for tons of bugs in js code. And reusing methods in the way you implied, i.e by rebinding them to another "this" is a very questionable programming style anyway.

Comment: There is absolutely nothing broken about `this`, only with beginners’ perception of it.

Comment: @PointedEars I think that might be a matter of opinion, as it works differently from any other language I know of and is a frustration for many even after they understand it. I guess broken might be the wrong word to use, as it does work as intended.

Answer (score -2):

I use the style bellow:

```
function MyClass(){
    var privateFunction = function(){

    }

    this.publicFunction = function(){
        privateFunction();
    }

}
```

For me this is much more intuitive than using the prototype way, but you'll reach a similar result combining `apply()` method.

Also, you have another good patterns, [Literal Object Notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5754538/javascript-object-literal-notation-vs-plain-functions-and-performance-implicatio), [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/blog/tag/revealing-module-pattern/)

But, if you want to change the reference to `this` associate of a function use the [Function.prototype.apply()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), you can see at [this sample](http://jsbin.com/kuxug/6/watch?js,console) a way to change the global `this` to your object.

Comment: Scope has nothing to do with `this`; so `Function.prototype.apply()` has nothing to do with scope, it has to do with the `this` value in the called function. That is a common misconception in beginners.

Comment: Your (now corrected) style has the disadvantage that with each constructor call you are creating (here: two) new `Function` instances. IOW, for creating one hundred `myClass` instances, you are creating *three hundred* objects and reserving heap memory for them. This pattern makes sense if you really need instance-private parts; in all other cases it is overkill and constitutes massive overhead. BTW, by convention the identifier of a constructor starts *uppercase*.

Comment: I don't know this too, but I'm using only for unique instances. I usually use a functional programming style to iterate on multiple objects.

Comment: You do not need a constructor for a singleton in these languages.

Comment: Sure... but as I sad, I don't use this way of declaration, tks a lot.

Comment: I used the word scope because, when you change the `this` object you get access to properties referenced with the `this` object.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51311/discussion-between-claudio-santos-and-pointedears)