# Why closure value is lost?

Tags: javascript, closures

I came across the following issue:

```
function Parent(value) {
     var callback = function() {
         console.log(value);
         //actually the following line was found in the code
         var value; //<- hoisting, takes effect first
     }
     callback();
}

Parent(); //undefined
Parent('Wow!'); //undefined, closure value was lost?!
```

Both Parent calls logged 'undefined' message, but I really expected to see 'Wow!' value on the second call.

Issue can be reproduced here: http://jsfiddle.net/5tgsj37e/3/

Related question: [Why does this closure-scoped variable lose its value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5740140/why-does-this-closure-scoped-variable-lose-its-value)

Comment: Why do you have `console.log('value');`? Wouldn't this log "value" every time? And is it "undefined" in the console? And, as @charlietfl said, `url` is not defined, so the AJAX may not work at all. Is this your full code?

Comment: where is `url` defined? Also `Parent()` doesn't return anything so it's not unexpected to have it log undefined. What exactly are you expecting to happen here?

Comment: updated both var url = anyUrl; and console.log(value);

Comment: I can't reproduce it. http://jsfiddle.net/barmar/5tgsj37e/

Comment: It depends on whether your 'anyUrl' is valid, you just put a success callback so if  'anyUrl' is not valid, it won't get executed.

Comment: @NaturalLam If it doesn't get executed, it won't log `undefined`, either.

Comment: @spirit _"Both Parent calls logged 'undefined' message, but I really expected to see 'Wow!' value on the second call."_ `js` at Question appear to return expected results http://jsfiddle.net/02keLwyp/

Comment: please, let me check it locally again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason was Hoisting:

```
(function Parent(value) {
     var child = function() {
         console.log(value);
         var value; //hoisting clears closure value
     }
     child();
}('Wow!'));
```

While is all right:

```
(function Parent(value) {
     var child = function() {
         console.log(value);
         //var value;
     }
     child();
}('Wow!'));
```

I did not notice *var value* in the Parent function yesterday.

Code sample: http://jsfiddle.net/5tgsj37e/3/

---

Additional notes about the code style.

**Strict mode:** Putting child outside of parent will create a global. Therefore "use strict" strict mode should be considered as a good practise while using closures.

**Explicit closure declaration** If you want to use closure value in a child function, it is better to wrap the Child into a closure explicitly. This will prevent global variable creation if one day your child starts living outside of the parent. That will also throw an error that there is no value.

```
(function Parent(value) {
     (function(childValue) {
         var child = function() {
            console.log(childValue);
         }
         child();
     )(value));
}('Wow!'));
```

**Note about closures:** Closure is created per function call, not per function declaration.

Answer (score 2):

In this example, `Parent` has no return statement and thus always returns `undefined`. `Parent` also does not itself invoke `console.log` and therefore does not log anything to the console. The anonymous function created within it and assigned to `var callback` invokes `console.log`. This is then passed as a success callback to `jQuery.ajax()` through your `ajaxCall` function.

The anonymous `callback` function will be invoked upon success of the asynchronous ajax request. Success of course according to [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) for ajax requests.

As the results seem impossible to reproduce with the code as is, perhaps there is additional code in your `Parent` function somewhere that deletes the `value` parameter or otherwise sets it to `undefined`. Parameters and variables closed over by inner functions do not get garbage collected  unless they have a `0` reference count.

Comment: And in my case the string value seems to be garbage collected .

Comment: What JavaScript engine is being used?

Comment: This is Chrome browser. I have removed the ajax call and the issue is still reproduced. So it's a closure question.

Comment: Perhaps there is additional code in your Parent function somewhere that sets it to undefined. Yes, it was hoisting. The var value; statement was somewhere below.